# X=Y+Z, know the distribution of X, under which conditions can I recover(pin down) the distribution of Y and Z?

Tags: probability-distributions, inverse-problems

You may add any conditions you want if this is doable. Otherwise, it would be great if you could provide any impossibility result.

Also greatly appreciate it if you could guide me to related problems, results or papers.
Many thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

In general you can't say which distributions gave you $X$.

However, with some additional restrictions you can tell something about the family of that distribution.

An example is family of Gaussian distributions.
Famous Cramer's theorem says that if $X$ has normal distribution, then $Y$ and $Z$ also must have normal distribution.

See [Cramer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%99s_decomposition_theorem)

Also there is Raikov theorem which tells the same for Poisson distributed random variable.
And there is theorem about sums of normal and Poisson distribution. So that if you know that $X$ has the same distribution as Poisson+Normal, then $Y$ and $Z$ are necessarily like that (one of them is Poisson one is normal).

Hope that helped.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is quite helpful!! I read the theorem link you provided, which says that this problem relates to decomposition theory for random variables as sums of independent variables.

Comment: Yes of course. This is only for independent random variables. One additional note. Even In a general class of infinite divisible distribution or stable distribution (in both cases) you can't for sure say which distributions gave rise to $X$, even though Poisson and normal are in that classes.

Comment: @kolobokish You seem to take independence very lightly. I consider your answer as wrong and misleading because you claimed Cramer's Theorem to hold without independence. Please edit your answer.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the note. Indeed, except for a few quite restrictive special cases, in general we cannot reverse engineer the distribution of Y and Z.

Comment: Sorry. I meant "not only". I'm sorry.